# python equivalent for MATLABS vratiotest

Tags: python, matlab

I am following the book `Algorithmic Trading` and I am on `Chapter 2:  The Basics of Mean Reversion`.

I have a few pairs and their close prices and I want to check the spread of which pair is mean-reverting.

The book uses MATLAB for all its programming and I am using Python.

First, there was a mention of `adf` function in MATLAB's package and its equivalent python code is:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
ad = adfuller(spread, maxlag = 1)
```

Then there is a mention of `cadf` and I think its equivalent python code is:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import coint
t_statistic, p_value, crit_value = coint(x, y)
```

However, I cannot find the python equivalent for `MATLAB`'s `vratiotest`.

Please let me know if there is a python function which performs same as `MATLAB`'s `vratiotest`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These may not be exactly what you are looking for:

https://arch.readthedocs.io/en/latest/unitroot/generated/arch.unitroot.VarianceRatio.html

```
arch.unitroot.VarianceRatio

from arch.unitroot import VarianceRatio
```

---

Here is the python code for **Variance Ratio Test - Lo and MacKinlay**

https://mingze-gao.com/posts/lomackinlay1988/